# istio gateway Not launching internal links, how to fix that?

Tags: kubernetes, aks, istio

I have deployed application in kubernetes.
It is working if we expose to a default load balancer service in azure kubernetes.
But, after setting a virtual service linked with istio ingress gateway, it is launching only the home page, none of the links are working like /admin /login.

I have added entries for /admin and /login already in virtual service but it is not opening those pages.

kiali launched using

```
istioctl dashboard kiali
```

When I check logs in [kiali](http://localhost:20001/kiali/console/namespaces/istio-system/workloads/istio-ingressgateway?tab=logs&rangeDuration=600&refresh=15000).

```
[2021-07-18T08:19:51.304Z] "GET /admin/ HTTP/1.1" 404 NR route_not_found - "-" 0 0 0 - "10.244.1.1" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.164 Safari/537.36" "bc1ce347-4151-947b-b3d5-4c08003889a2" "20.85.0.248" "-" - - 10.244.1.9:8080 10.244.1.1:4441 - -

[2021-07-18T08:19:53.400Z] "GET /login/ HTTP/1.1" 404 NR route_not_found - "-" 0 0 0 - "10.244.1.1" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.164 Safari/537.36" "78f9d59e-6126-94f6-99e3-cbffe98e274f" "20.85.0.248" "-" - - 10.244.1.9:8080 10.244.1.1:4441 - -

[2021-07-18T08:19:56.286Z] "GET /login HTTP/1.1" 301 - via_upstream - "-" 0 0 4 4 "10.244.1.1" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.164 Safari/537.36" "be2ff6b8-751d-9150-9d6a-936a436f7fef" "20.85.0.248" "10.244.1.50:3000" outbound|8080||node-service.default.svc.cluster.local 10.244.1.9:59678 10.244.1.9:8080 10.244.1.1:4441 - -

[2021-07-18T08:19:56.525Z] "GET /login/ HTTP/1.1" 404 NR route_not_found - "-" 0 0 0 - "10.244.1.1" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.164 Safari/537.36" "f821db0b-cc9d-9b8c-9769-71ac7636a87e" "20.85.0.248" "-" - - 10.244.1.9:8080 10.244.1.1:4441 - -

[2021-07-18T08:20:00.198Z] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 - via_upstream - "-" 0 2804 4 4 "10.244.1.1" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.164 Safari/537.36" "43c37e75-f0ce-9474-bc4d-ea4459772f6d" "20.85.0.248" "10.244.1.50:3000" outbound|8080||node-service.default.svc.cluster.local 10.244.1.9:59678 10.244.1.9:8080 10.244.1.1:4441 - -

[2021-07-18T08:20:00.457Z] "GET /static/todo/logo.png HTTP/1.1" 404 NR route_not_found - "-" 0 0 0 - "10.244.1.1" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.164 Safari/537.36" "a26d3710-3868-96b6-9d6d-7f6ee05dc131" "20.85.0.248" "-" - - 10.244.1.9:8080 10.244.1.1:4441 - -

[2021-07-18T08:20:34.337Z] "GET /login/ HTTP/1.1" 404 NR route_not_found - "-" 0 0 0 - "10.244.1.1" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.164 Safari/537.36" "e8e73933-f95e-90a7-bdf4-ad39352982c5" "20.85.0.248" "-" - - 10.244.1.9:8080 10.244.1.1:4441 - -

[2021-07-18T08:20:37.506Z] "GET /login/ HTTP/1.1" 404 NR route_not_found - "-" 0 0 0 - "10.244.1.1" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.164 Safari/537.36" "bee90116-2d78-99dd-a4b7-fede0641fed8" "20.85.0.248" "-" - - 10.244.1.9:8080 10.244.1.1:4441 - -

[2021-07-18T08:20:40.191Z] "GET /login/ HTTP/1.1" 404 NR route_not_found - "-" 0 0 0 - "10.244.1.1" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.164 Safari/537.36" "f9df634e-743f-9699-a85d-40926db41ca4" "20.85.0.248" "-" - - 10.244.1.9:8080 10.244.1.1:4441 - -
```

Please suggest how to fix this?

The sample app docker [link](https://hub.docker.com/repository/docker/uday1kiran/todoapp).

The kubernetes yaml files used:

### Deployment.yaml

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: node-service
  labels:
    app: nodeapp
    service: node-service
spec:
  selector:
    app: nodeapp
  ports:
    - name: http
      port: 8080
      targetPort: 3000 #80

---
apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  name: nodeapp-details
  labels:
    account: nodeapp-details
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: nodeapp-deployment
  labels:
    app: nodeapp
    version: v1
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: nodeapp
      version: v1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: nodeapp
        version: v1
    spec:
      serviceAccountName: nodeapp-details
      containers:
        - name: nginx
          image: uday1kiran/todoapp:1.0 #nginx
          imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
          ports:
            - containerPort: 3000 #80
              name: nodeapp-port
          #securityContext:
          #runAsUser: 1000
```

### virtualservice.yaml

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: nodeserver
spec:
  hosts:
    - "*"
  gateways:
    - node-gateway
  http:
    - match:
        - uri:
            exact: /
        - uri:
            exact: /admin
        - uri:
            exact: /login
      route:
        - destination:
            host: node-service
            port:
              number: 8080
```

### gateway.yaml

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: Gateway
metadata:
  name: node-gateway
spec:
  selector:
    istio: ingressgateway # use istio default controller
  servers:
  - port:
      number: 80
      name: http
      protocol: HTTP
    hosts:
    - "*"
```

The yaml files are in this [repository](https://github.com/uday1kiran/service-mesh/tree/main/istio/sample%20django)

Answer (score 0):

You are getting 404 errors because you used `exact`:

```
http:
    - match:
        - uri:
            exact: /
        - uri:
            exact: /admin
        - uri:
            exact: /login
```

However, you are trying to reach other endpoints, e.g.

> "GET /admin/ HTTP/1.1"
>
> "GET /login/ HTTP/1.1"

You are trying to reach endpoints that have an extra sign `/` at the end. You can edit your yaml by changing `exact` to `regex`, or you can add additional options with the extra `/` character at the end. You can also read more about `StringMatch` [here](https://istio.io/latest/docs/reference/config/networking/virtual-service/#StringMatch).

Comment: Hello @uday. Does this [answer your question](https://serverfault.com/help/someone-answers)?